# Date range tally table grouping with bad performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, group-by

I have a stored procedure that is currently hitting the TempDb pretty hard, making the query run both slow and sometimes consuming a lot of disk space (growing TempDb). I am taking data such as this:

```
ID          StartDate               EndDate
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1           2013-06-17 00:09:59.270 2013-09-25 00:09:59.270
2           2013-06-22 00:10:30.077 2013-07-22 00:10:30.077
```

And need to group it per item (ID), Year and Month plus keep a count of the number of days per month, given the range in the source data, hopefully ending up with this (minus late night calculation errors on my part):

```
ID  TheYear TheMonth    NumberOfDays
--- ------- ----------- ------------
1   2013    6           14
1   2013    7           31
1   2013    8           31
1   2013    9           25
2   2013    6           9
2   2013    7           22
```

This calculation is today done using a stored procedure much like this one:

```
INSERT INTO GroupedData
( 
        ID,
        TheYear ,
        TheMonth ,
        NumberOfDays
)
SELECT  ID,
        YEAR(StartDate + v.number) AS TheYear,
        MONTH(StartDate + v.number) AS TheMonth,
        COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDays
FROM    dbo.RawData 
        INNER JOIN 
        master..spt_values v ON v.type = 'P'
            AND v.number <= DATEDIFF(d, StartDate, EndDate)
GROUP BY ID,
        YEAR(StartDate + v.number),
        MONTH(StartDate + v.number)
```

Now, this seems to work fine calculation-wise, but it is not very performant. It consumes a lot of disk (TempDb) and CPU resources. The input table is between 100'000 and a million rows. The real source date ranges are below 50 years, usually 5-10 years.

My *guess* is that the use of the Tally table (`master..spt_values`) join causes the query to blow out of proportions. Note: I am using a generated 'numbers' table in the real code to deal with the fact that the Tally table only consists of 2048 entries.

So, is there a better way to do this calculation? Cursors? CTE? Temp tables? Other magic?

Comment: The first problem is that `master` has 2048 values which is sufficient for 5.6 years only. You are losing days. The second is number of rows before aggregation. With average span of 2000 days per record you get 100000 * 2000 = 200,000,000 rows. You might try spawning months only and calculating days per month taking into account edge cases (first and last month) rather than counting days. This will remove `group by` too.

Comment: Thanks, yes the master is only there to show the principle, I am using a generated 'numbers' table to deal with the 2048 limitation in my real code. Added note about that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     INSERT INTO GroupedData
( 
        ID,
        TheYear ,
        TheMonth ,
        NumberOfDays
)
SELECT  ID,
        YEAR(StartDate) + v.number  AS TheYear,
        MONTH(StartDate) + v.number AS TheMonth,
        COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDays
FROM    dbo.RawData 
        INNER JOIN 
        master..spt_values v ON v.type = 'P'
            AND v.number <= DATEDIFF(d, StartDate, EndDate)
GROUP BY ID,
        YEAR(StartDate) + v.number,
        MONTH(StartDate) + v.number
```